# Cant get predicates to work properly with XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, xpath

This code  prints out `book1book2`. I just want it to print out `book2`. Have I not specified the predicate properly?

(Note I'm not really looking for an alternative way to print out "book2" as this is a simplification of my problem - I more wishing to understand what I'm doing wrong as I'm learning c#).

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;

String xpathStg =
    "<bookstore> <book>book1</book> <book>book2</book> </bookstore>";

XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xpathStg));

XPathNavigator nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator NodeIter = nav.Select("/bookstore/book[last()]");

Console.WriteLine("NodeIter.Current.Value=" + NodeIter.Current.Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consume the XPathNodeIterator with e.g.

`foreach (XPathNavigator book in NodeIter) { Console.WriteLine(book.Value); }`

Or at least call `NodeIter.MoveNext()` once before accessing `Current.Value`.